# Yii2 Autoloading Extension Classes

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've created a private repository on Bitbucket with an external module and have added it to my dependency list in a project's composer.json file.
The problem is that after "composer install" I got my module downloaded in the vendor folder but it throws a ReflectionException:

> Class example\news\Module does not exist

external module composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "example/yii2-module-news",
    "description": "News",
    "type": "yii2-extension",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "extension", "news"],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "me"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "example\\news\\": ""
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget" : "~1.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-helpers": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf"    : "*"
    }
}
```

project composer.json

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "example/yii2-module-news",
        "version": "master",
        "source": {
          "type": "git",
          "url": "git@bitbucket.org:example/yii2-module-news.git",
          "reference": "master"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php do'nt contain any recor about new external module

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'yii\\twig\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-twig'),
    'yii\\swiftmailer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer'),
    'yii\\jui\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-jui'),
    'yii\\gii\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-gii'),
    'yii\\faker\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-faker'),
    'yii\\debug\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-debug'),
    'yii\\composer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-composer'),
    'yii\\codeception\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-codeception'),
    'yii\\bootstrap\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap'),
    'yii\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2'),
    'voskobovich\\behaviors\\' => array($vendorDir . '/voskobovich/yii2-many-many-behavior/src'),
    'skeeks\\widget\\chosen\\' => array($vendorDir . '/skeeks/yii2-widget-chosen'),
    'rmrevin\\yii\\fontawesome\\' => array($vendorDir . '/rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome'),
    'mihaildev\\elfinder\\' => array($vendorDir . '/mihaildev/yii2-elfinder'),
    'kartik\\tree\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-tree-manager'),
    'kartik\\select2\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2'),
    'kartik\\growl\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-widget-growl'),
    'kartik\\form\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform'),
    'kartik\\dialog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-dialog'),
    'kartik\\datetime\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker'),
    'kartik\\daterange\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-date-range'),
    'kartik\\date\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker'),
    'kartik\\base\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base'),
    'dosamigos\\ckeditor\\' => array($vendorDir . '/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/src'),
    'dmstr\\' => array($vendorDir . '/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset'),
    'creocoder\\nestedsets\\' => array($vendorDir . '/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets/src'),
    'cebe\\markdown\\' => array($vendorDir . '/cebe/markdown'),
    'Faker\\' => array($vendorDir . '/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker'),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That composer repositories configuration looks too complex. Should be working much easier for example with:

```
  "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:example/yii2-module-news.git"
    },
  ]
```